# Black screen when upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, update-manager, 16.04

I have a custom pc with an nvidia gpu that I wanted to update from 14.04 to 16.04 but I ran into a problem. I started the update with `sudo update manager -d` and it downloaded everything alright. When it started installing, in the middle the screen went black and the monitors were showing no input.

I unplugged the hdmi cable and plugged it back in and it showed my desktop for a little bit but went black again. Plugging into either gpu or motherboard makes no difference. The computer does not respond to any keyboard or mouse inputs but the they do seem to be on. I tried Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F1 to F12 but nothing is showing up. It's been like this for a few hours now.

I noticed this happened after I manually locked the computer with Super + L but I'm not sure if this is the cause of it. Should I hard reset my computer and do a fresh install if it did indeed crash?

**Edit**: So I forced off my computer and restarted and now it boots to an all terminal screen. Top of the screen says 16.04 LTS on top and it has that reminder prompt for sudo. What should I do from here?

**Edit2:** So I managed to fix broken packages with `dpkg configure`. Now i boot to the longin screen but entering my password just displays wallpaper with no desktop. I tried reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` but it didnt work. I can switch to terminal with Ctrl + Alt + F1. Now what should I do?

**Edit3:** I ran a `sudo apt-get upgrade` and it boots to desktop now. I keep getting things to report crashes but its usable. Im going to go back to 14.04 and try again.

Comment: If you have some data which you need then boot live session and save that data somewhere, then do a full install

Comment: I created a snapshot with timeshift. Can I restore that from a livecd?

Answer (score 3):

So I was able to fix it myself in the end. Update manager popped up asking to do a partial upgrade and I went through with it and everything seems to work now.

Comment: I had the same issue and I followed essentially the same steps and resolved it.  +1, thanks!  With my upgrade attempt, my screen just went black when I tried to open up a terminal window while it was upgrading.  So maybe the lesson learned for me is don't try to open a terminal window while upgrading.